# Solve $AX+BY=C$ and $DX+EY=F$ given the matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given that $A=I, \ B=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 2 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}, \ C=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}, \ D=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 3 \\ 3 & 3\end{bmatrix}, \ E=\begin{bmatrix}4 & 4 \\ 4 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \ F=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 4 \\ 3 & 0\end{bmatrix},$ solve the system of equations:

$$\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcr}
    AX + BY & = & C \\
    DX + EY & = & F \\
  \end{array}
\right.$$

First equation gives $$AX = C-BY\Leftrightarrow X=C-BY$$ since $A$ is just the identity. The second equation gives $$DX=F-EY\Leftrightarrow X=D^{-1}(F-EY).$$

Setting the $X$'s equal I obtain

$$C-BY=D^{-1}(F-EY)\Leftrightarrow C-BY=D^{-1}F-D^{-1}EY \\ \Leftrightarrow -D^{-1}F+C=BY-D^{-1}EY=(B-D^{-1}E)Y.$$

And finally the solution for $Y$ is

$$Y=(B-D^{-1}E)^{-1}(C-D^{-1}F).$$

However, once i sett in the given matrices and compute, I can't get  the correct answer for $Y$, which is $Y=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}.$ Is the last equation above for $Y$ correct?

Comment: Halfway through your solution you set $X=I$ ... there is no justification for doing this.

Comment: Where? I can't see it

Comment: Setting the $X$'s equal I obtain ... lol ... Sorry my bad !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that $A=I$ this makes thing much easier than they might have been. Multply the first equation on the left by $D$ and then subtract it from the second equation 
\begin{eqnarray*}
(E-DB)Y=F-DC
\end{eqnarray*}
Now assuming $E-DB$ is invertible, left multiply by its inverse and we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
Y= (E-DB)^{-1}(F-DC) \\
X=C-B(E-DB)^{-1}(F-DC).
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

Gaussian elimination gives

$$X+A^{-1}BY=A^{-1}C, $$

then

$$(E-DA^{-1}B)Y=F-DA^{-1}C.$$

If $A=I$, this simplifies to

$$(E-DB)Y=F-DC.$$